# Private networks and port forwarding with Virtualbox not working together

Tags: virtualbox, port-forwarding

I have two virtual machines inside a Windows host. I would like to setup a virtual network (not bridged) such that both machines are able to communicate with each other. In addition one of the host should be available to access over port forwarding from the host.

I got both machines communicating with each other, by adding each machine a second interface connected to "Internal Network" (named intnet). However, the port forwarding on the machine is not working. This a simple diagram of the network I would like to have.

```
 Host (port forward 2222 to port 22 of VM1) 
  | \
  |  \ 
VM1<->VM2
```

Comment: How many network adapters does VM1 have, and how exactly are they configured? What OS is running inside VM1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you can do everything with the command line, I do post here an answer that show a point and click solution.

First create a new NatNetwork (go to File->Preference):

[image: NewNatNetwork]

Than set it up to use a different IP Range then the range used by the default NAT Network (which is 10.0.2.0/24):

[image: Network Range]

The next thing add all your VM a second Network interface, which is connected to that network:

[image: Multiple interfaces]

On one of the machines you should enable port forwarding from the Host to the guest:
[image]

Now you can ssh from the host to port 2222, you will than be able to connect to VM1 (which has two IP address 10.0.2.8 for example and another IP 10.0.3.2) from which you can ssh to the machine VM2 which has the IP address  10.0.3.3 (for example).

Et viola, now you have ssh from host to multiple machine.